# Not able to access json from Google cloud deployed app url

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-platform

I deployed a Flask api through google cloud using gcloud app deploy and can see JSON with browser at the site --appspot.com/users

I coded in Android Studio and can access other public JSON data and see it displayed in the app. But nothing shows up for the JSON that was deployed to google. No errors show up either.

```
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("");

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        myapi api= retrofit.create(myapi.class);

        Call<List<model>> call = api.getmodels();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<model>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<model>> call, Response<List<model>> response){
                List<model> data=response.body();
                for(int i =0; i<data.size(); i++)
                    tv.append(" SL No:" + data.get(i).getUserId()+" \n Name :"+data.get(i).getName()+ "\n\n\n");
            }
```

This is the code in MainActivity.java and the code below in myapi.java

```
public interface myapi {

    @GET("users")
    Call<List<model>> getmodels();
}
```

Below is the code in model.java file:

```
    String userId, name, title;

     public model(String userId, String name, String title){
         this.userId = userId;
         this.name = name;
         this.title = title;

     }

    public String getUserId(){
         return userId;
    }


    public void setUserId(String userId) {
         this.userId = userId;
    }
```

this is the JSON content:

```
{"data": 
{"userId": 
{"0": "a1b", 
"1": "a2c", 
"2": "b1b", 
"3": "b2c"}, 
"name": 
{"0": "Joe", 
"1": "Jenny", 
"2": "Jack", 
"3": "Jill"}, 
"city": 
{"0": "Paris", 
"1": "London", 
"2": "London", 
"3": "Berlin"}, 
"locations": 
{"0": "['0001', '0002', '0008']", 
"1": "['0003', '0004']", 
"2": "['0003', '0005']", 
"3": "['0006', '0007']"}}}
```

This is the JSON I can access:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 4,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 5,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 6,
    "id": 6,
    "title": "qui ullam ratione quibusdam voluptatem quia omnis",
    "completed": false
  }]
```

Here is the flask code:

```
users_path = './data/users.csv'
locs_path = './data/locations.csv'

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Users(Resource):
    def get(self):
        data = pd.read_csv(users_path) 
        data = data.to_dict()
        return {'data': data}, 200

    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('userId', required=True, location='args')
        parser.add_argument('name', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('city', required=True)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        data = pd.read_csv(users_path)

        if args['userId'] in list(data['userId']):
            return {
                'message': f"'{args['userId']}' already exists."
            }, 409
        else:
            new_data = pd.DataFrame({
                'userId': [args['userId']],
                'name': [args['name']],
                'city': [args['city']],
                'locations': [[]]
            })

            data = data.append(new_data, ignore_index=True)
            data.to_csv(users_path, index=False)  
            return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200  

    def put(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser() 
        parser.add_argument('userId', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('location', required=True)
        args = parser.parse_args()


        data = pd.read_csv(users_path)
        
        if args['userId'] in list(data['userId']):
            data['locations'] = data['locations'].apply(
                lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)
            )
            user_data = data[data['userId'] == args['userId']]

            user_data['locations'] = user_data['locations'].values[0] \
                .append(args['location'])

            data.to_csv(users_path, index=False)
            return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200

        else:
            return {
                'message': f"'{args['userId']}' user not found."
            }, 404

    def delete(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser() 
        parser.add_argument('userId', required=True) 
        args = parser.parse_args() 
        
        data = pd.read_csv(users_path)
        
        if args['userId'] in list(data['userId']):
            data = data[data['userId'] != args['userId']]
            
            data.to_csv(users_path, index=False)
            return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200
        else:
            return {
                'message': f"'{args['userId']}' user not found."
            }, 404

                    
class Locations(Resource):
    def get(self):
        data = pd.read_csv(locs_path) 
        return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200
    
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser() 
        parser.add_argument('locationId', required=True, type=int)
        parser.add_argument('name', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('rating', required=True)
        args = parser.parse_args() 
        
        data = pd.read_csv(locs_path)
    
        if args['locationId'] in list(data['locationId']):
            return {
                'message': f"'{args['locationId']}' already exists."
            }, 409
        else:
            new_data = pd.DataFrame({
                'locationId': [args['locationId']],
                'name': [args['name']],
                'rating': [args['rating']]
            })
            data = data.append(new_data, ignore_index=True)
            data.to_csv(locs_path, index=False) 
            return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200 
    
    def patch(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('locationId', required=True, type=int) 
        parser.add_argument('name', store_missing=False)
        parser.add_argument('rating', store_missing=False)
        args = parser.parse_args() 
        
        data = pd.read_csv(locs_path)
        
        if args['locationId'] in list(data['locationId']):
            user_data = data[data['locationId'] == args['locationId']]
            
            if 'name' in args:
                user_data['name'] = args['name']
            if 'rating' in args:
                user_data['rating'] = args['rating']
            
            data[data['locationId'] == args['locationId']] = user_data
            data.to_csv(locs_path, index=False)
            return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200
        
        else:
            return {
                'message': f"'{args['locationId']}' location does not exist."
            }, 404
    
    def delete(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser() 
        parser.add_argument('locationId', required=True, type=int)
        args = parser.parse_args() 

        data = pd.read_csv(locs_path)
        
        if args['locationId'] in list(data['locationId']):
            data = data[data['locationId'] != args['locationId']]
            data.to_csv(locs_path, index=False)
            return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200
        
        else:
            return {
                'message': f"'{args['locationId']}' location does not exist."
            }


api.add_resource(Users, '/users')
api.add_resource(Locations, '/locations')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

How can I get access and display the users JSON content? Why can't android studio read my JSON?

Is it the format of the users JSON content that I need to change? Or to include "{data:" in the path to userIds and names?

Comment: I didn't catch your question. You deployed on App ENgine and your service answer correctly right? Now, you are on Android Studio, you are trying to get your JSON, but it does not work, correct? So now: why Android studio can't read your JSON? That's the question?

Comment: Arf, I have an idea. Can you share your flask code also?

Comment: Can you change your return `return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200`, by this return `return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200, {'content-type': 'application/json'}`and try again? If it works, I will answer your question

Comment: I changed the return line and it didn't work.